# Axis POJO clients

Tags: java, web-services, soap, axis

I am learning to use Apache Axis Library

In the documentation it is shown how to create a web service from a POJO class.

But for clients it mentions only Axis2 DataBinding Framework, XMLBeans, and JiBX databinding

So, is there any way to use POJO classes as SOAP clients.

and which is better of the 4 in terms of performance and usability.

Answer (score 0):

This link may help you to decide upon the data binding that you need. [Axis2 Data Binding](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-java3/)

My personal experience with ADB and XMLBeans is that, out of these two ADB is pretty simple and straightforward, but when your wsdl is complex then you need to do a hell lot of manual coding. On the other hand, XMLBeans looks complex but the classes that it generates is easy to use.